# convert dd monthname yyyy to dd-mm-yy and check with current system date

Tags: date, vbscript

I want to lock or reboot/shutdown Windows system if antivirus is not updated more than 5 days.

So I decided to get the last updated data from the AV Application and redirected to text document. But the last updated date showing in logs as `"dd monthname yyyy"`.

I want to match this date with current system date. I need to validate the last updated date with 5 days before of system date. If AV is not updated 5 or more days I want to lock or reboot the system. I want to accomplish this by using vbsrcipt so that I'll deploy in group policy.

This is my sample out log file below from the Mcafee AV.

```
CommonShell Command Line Scanner Lite (VSCORE.15.6.0.1551)

Engine Version     : 5900.7806
Engine Load Time   : 5312 milliseconds
AV     DAT Version : 8673.0000   668571 detections   Built 03 October 2017

Extra DAT          :                  0 detections
```

Please help with vbscript code to accomplish the same.

Answer (score -1):

With a little help from SetLocale, CDate() understands english monthnames:

```
Option Explicit

SetLocale "en-us" ' now it understands "October", but won't do m/d/y

Dim d : d = Date()
Dim s
For Each s In Split("03 October 2017*01 October 2017*29 September 2017", "*")
    Dim di : di = CDate(s)
    Dim dd : dd = Datediff("d", d, di)
    WScript.Echo d, di, dd, CStr(dd < -4)
Next
```

(german) output:

```
cscript 46570030.vbs
04.10.2017 03.10.2017 -1 Falsch
04.10.2017 01.10.2017 -3 Falsch
04.10.2017 29.09.2017 -5 Wahr
```